# Find parent documents based on child doc value

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We are using **haschild** query to find the parent documents based on the condition.

We have two types

1. funnels
2. pages

**funnels sample doc**

```
 {
   "funnel_id": "12345",
   "path": "a -> b -> c"
 }

 {
   "funnel_id": "56789",
   "path": "a -> d"
 }
```

** pages sample doc**

```
{
  "_parent": "12345",
  "visited_page": "/home"
}

{
  "_parent": "12345",
  "visited_page": "/cart"
}

{
  "_parent": "12345",
  "visited_page": "/cart"
}
```

**Condition1:**

Find parent doc based child doc "**visited_page**" value contains "home".

```
"must" : {
  "has_child" : {
    "query" : {
      "regexp" : {
        "url" : {
          "value" : ".*home.*",
          "flags_value" : 65535
        }
      }
    },
    "child_type" : "session_pages"
  }
}
```

It works perfectly.

**Condition2**

Find parent doc based child doc "**visited_page**" value does NOT contains "home".

```
"must_not" : {
  "has_child" : {
    "query" : {
      "regexp" : {
        "url" : {
          "value" : ".*home.*",
          "flags_value" : 65535
        }
      }
    },
    "child_type" : "session_pages"
  }
}
```

But this query returned wrong results.

***Output of the query***

```
  {
  "funnel_id": "12345",
  "path": "a -> b -> c"
 }

 {
   "funnel_id": "56789",
   "path": "a -> d"
 }
```

You can see the parent id(funnel_id:12345) child doc contains visited page with value "home". But that also returns.

**Expected Result**

```
  {
   "funnel_id": "56789",
   "path": "a -> d"
 }
```

Comment: May you please clarify for the "Condition 2". You want to retrieve only those `funnel_id` documents which **do not** have a child that matches `".*home.*"` regexp?

Comment: You want to retrieve only those funnel_id documents which do not have a child that matches ".*home.*" regexp?

Yes, exactly. Here funnel_id is the relationship identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sorry, I can't reproduce the behavior you are facing. Is that right that in the sample there are 3 `page` documents all corresponding to the same `_parent: 12345`? By the way, the query from "Condition 2" returns me not only matching `parent` documents, but also `child` documents as well. May you please fix the formatting and also provide the mapping you are using?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev will update the mapping. What we want is, we want the parent documents which all the child documents doesn't match the pattern .*home.*

Comment: You mentioned you'll add the mapping of the fields. Please do, together also with any custom analyzers you might have defined.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are "must_not"ing in the wrong spot
try:

```
    "must" : {
  "has_child" : {
    "query" : {
      "regexp" : {
        "url" : {
          "must_not": {
               "value" : ".*home.*"
                       },
          "flags_value" : 65535
        }
      }
    },
    "child_type" : "session_pages"
  }
}
```